# Passing variables between procedures

Tags: c++, class, oop, variables, procedural-programming

I'm working on a C++ card game and I'm having an issue where I have variables in different procedures but they don't seem to keep their values in each method.

I am a total beginner when it comes to working with procedures, so apologies for what must seem like such a simple issue.

Here's my code for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

class player {
public:
    string name = "";
    int credit = 0;
    int bet = 0;
};

class cards {
public:
    string suit;
    int number = 0;
};

void Initialise() {
    //initialise Vars
    string suits[4] = { "Coins", "Flasks", "Sabers", "Staves" };
    int values[15] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
}

void DefineCards(cards Card[60]) {
    
    //Define Card Values
    for (int c = 0; c < 60; c++) {

        if (c >= 0 && c <= 14) {
            Card[c].suit = "Coins";
            Card[c].number = c;
        }
        else if (c >= 15 && c <= 29) {
            Card[c].suit = "Flasks";
            Card[c].number = c - 14;
        }
        else if (c >= 30 && c <= 44) {
            Card[c].suit = "Sabers";
            Card[c].number = c - 29;
        }
        else if (c >= 45 && c <= 60) {
            Card[c].suit = "Staves";
            Card[c].number = c - 44;
        }

    }
}

void CreatePlayer(player CurrentPlayer) {
    

    bool correct = false;
    string choice;

    do {
        cout << "Please input your name: " << endl;
        cin >> CurrentPlayer.name;

        cout << "Your name is " << CurrentPlayer.name << "? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == "y" || choice == "Y") {
            correct = true;
        }
        else {
            correct = false;
        }
    } while (correct == false);
    
    CurrentPlayer.credit = 1000;
}

//Game Procedeures

void Betting(player CurrentPlayer){
    int pot = 0;
    int bet = 0;

    bool correct = false;
    do {
        cout << "Current Bet: " << CurrentPlayer.bet << " Total Pot: " << pot << " Credit: " << CurrentPlayer.credit << "\n\n";
        cout << "Please enter a bet to begin: " << endl;
        cin >> bet;

        if (bet <= CurrentPlayer.credit) {
            correct = true;
        }
        else if (bet > CurrentPlayer.credit) {
            cout << "You don't have enough credits.";
        }
        else if (bet < 1) {
            cout << "That's an impossible value, Please try again.";
        }
    } while (correct == false);
    pot = pot + bet;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cards Card[60];
    player CurrentPlayer;
    
    //Initialisation procedeures
    Initialise();
    DefineCards(Card);
    CreatePlayer(CurrentPlayer);
    
    //Game
    Betting(CurrentPlayer);
    
    //Display Cards

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably pass by reference.

Comment: In the function signatures of `CreatePlayer` and `Betting` change it to `player&` if you want the information of the player to be passed into the function and manipulated by it.

Comment: `void DefineCards(cards Card[60])` turns to be `void DefineCards(cards* Card)`, so you indeed modify cards. but size cannot be checked. "ugly" `void DefineCards(cards (&Card)[60])` would be the safe way to pass array by reference.